# Lightweight C++11 run-time array?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdvector

I'm working on smaller, embedded platforms.  `std::array<>` is great when we know the size of an array at compile time.  We will use `std::vector<>` in some cases for run-time arrays when we need to add and remove items.

That area in-between, where we only find out the (constant) size of the array at run-time, is more tricky.  We are currently using `std::unique_ptr<[]>` in most of these cases.  It is sized at run-time and doesn't have the overhead of vector.  But there are drawbacks - the syntax isn't great, it is tricky to use in std algorithms without `std::begin` & `std::end`, etc.

I'm very tempted to make my own RuntimeArray<> that wraps std::unique_ptr<[]> or something similar.  Are there other options I should consider?  Maybe something in a 3rd party library worth looking at?

Edit - Lots of questions about the overhead of `std::vector<>`.  I've tried to put together a minimal example at https://godbolt.org/g/JT96eE.  You can play with it to see the difference in generated assembly - some 30-50% more for vector.  I've seen other cases which are more dramatic, 3-4x the code for vector.  This isn't a big deal on desktop apps and similar, but for embedded and game development, usually vector is avoided for these sort of reasons.

Comment: What is the overhead of using `std::vector`?

Comment: There should not be any issue with vector you can always use reserve initially at runtime

Comment: _I'm very tempted to make my own RuntimeArray<> that wraps std::unique_ptr<[]> or something similar._ Why? `std::vector` does this at least as perfect if used properly. Have a look at [`std::vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) (or the corresponding constructors) or [`std::vector::reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) if you still want to fill it with [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). `std::vector` strongly resembles arrays - no need to use `begin()` and `end()` if

Comment: ...you don't like them...

Comment: Btw. `std::vector` provides range check in [`std::vector::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at). The version of MS (and probably of others as well) even provide range check `assert()`s in `std::vector::operator[]` (in debug mode only) which is great to catch stupid out of bound access bugs in development.

Comment: I've updated my question with an example at https://godbolt.org/g/JT96eE.  Just to clarify - I love `begin()` and `end()`, and was frustrated that I can't use them with `std::unique_ptr<[]>`

Comment: There was a TS `std::experimental::dynarray` proposal for a similar template class floating around some time ago - that might be a good source for inspiration on the interface if you can find it (though it seems to have disappeared from cppreference.com).